# Dependencies in a logical model mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am doing the logical model for a database, in which there is the entity Customer.
Each customer will have some "fixed" attributes (name, surname, address, telephone number..) and some others that have to be updated sometimes (username, password, age, weight...)

Now my problem is: do you recommend me to create two different tables, like this:

```
Customer ( CustomerID, Name, Surname, Address, telephone number ) 
Customer_Spe ( CustomerID, age, Username, Password, weight )
```

or, instead, a single one with all these attributes?

```
Customer ( CustomerID, Name, Surname, Address, telephone number, age, Username, Password, weight)
```

Can you justify your answer?

Comment: Opinion-based. Both options have both pros and cons.

Comment: which one would you chose ? @Akina

Answer (score 2):

In most databases, there is not a particular advantage to separating out attributes in a second table based on the frequency of updates.

There are valid reasons for separating out attributes:

- You might want PII (privacy) related attributes in a separate table to control access.
- You might want infrequently used attributes in a separate table to reduce the amount of data read for most queries.
- If the additional table is optional, then you might reduce data size by not having a row in the second table.
- If you had *very* volatile data with very frequent updates (think many per second), then you might want to separate out those columns to reduce contention on the rest of the data.

The data in your question looks like it is infrequently updated, so the last consideration would not apply.

Answer (score 1):

Theory said you have do tables with minimal set of columns, upto table with just one text field and ID.

Practically in most cases you have do all that in one table if it related to same entity and most SQLs query all those fields.

Many tables will add cpu time to join it and may greatly increase SQLs complexity. Large SQLs are hard to maintain.